# User not staying signed in after successfully signing in?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm integrating Firebase's google authentication into my React application and am running into an issue where the user is successfully signing in but when the page is refreshed he is no longer logged in.

I have a file `Firebase.js` where all my firebase functionality is located:

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    fb = firebase.initializeApp(config);
} else {
    fb = firebase.apps[0];
}

module.exports = {
    app: fb,
    db: fb.database(),
    auth: fb.auth,
    isUserSignedIn: () => {
        var user = fb.auth.currentUser;
        if (user) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    signIn: () => {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        fb.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
            console.log("Signed in using Google.");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error occured with sign in.");
            location.reload();
        });
    },
}
```

My app successfully loads the google sign in pop up and I get the message in the console `"Signed in using Google."`

However, in the React component where I'm checking whether the user is signed in, when the page refreshes it says the user isn't signed in:

```
import fb from '../../../Firebase';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const container = document.getElementById('navBar');
    let isSignedIn = fb.isUserSignedIn();
    console.log("Signed in: " + isSignedIn);
    ReactDOM.render(<UserLink props={{signedIn: isSignedIn }} />, container);
}
```

I checked in the firebase auth console and know for a fact that the user got authenticated, but for some reason my app is not picking up on that.

Can anybody please help me see what I'm doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [auth state change callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged) to get the login state rather than depending on it being immediately available when your code starts running at page load.  [An example is in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data).

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```